# Varieties in algebraic geometry, problem from Hassett's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is the problem 3.9 from Hassett's introduction to algebraic geometry.

We consider the varieties $V,W\subset\mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{C})$ defined by,
$$V=\{(x_1,x_2):x_1^4+x_2^4=1\}\text{ and }W=\{(x_1,x_2):x_1^2+x_2^2=1\}$$
and the morphism,
$$\begin{matrix}
\phi:&\mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{C})&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{C})\\
&(x_1,x_2)&\longrightarrow&(x_1^2,x_2^2)
\end{matrix}$$
Have to show that $\phi(V)\subset W$.

I think I'm missing something because my solution is so obvious and so easy, if you have $(x_1,x_2)\in V$ then $x_1^4+x_2^4=1$, so if you compute their image $\phi(x_1,x_2)=(x_1^2,x_2^2)$ and it's obvious that,
$$(x_1^2)^2+(x_2^2)^2=x_1^4+x_2^4=1\Rightarrow \phi(x_1,x_2)\in W$$

Comment: Believe in yourself.

Comment: but what is the point on this problem? is it to show something deeper?

Comment: Doubt there is anything deeper.

Comment: @Jorge No, there is nothing else to do for this exercise.